# Does 3.4.1/6 ignore the lookup of a name used in a function which is found in the function's parameter-declaration-clause?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lookup

3.4.1/6:

> A name used in the definition of a function following the function’s
>   *declarator-id*<sup>28</sup> that is a member of namespace `N` (where, only for the purpose of exposition, `N` could represent the global
>   scope) shall be declared before its use in the block in which it is
>   used or in one of its enclosing blocks (6.3) or, shall be declared
>   before its use in namespace `N` or, if `N` is a nested namespace, shall be
>   declared before its use in one of `N`’s enclosing namespaces.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace A {  
>     namespace N {  
>         void f();  
>     }  
> }  
>
> void A::N::f() {  
>     i = 5;  
>
>     // The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:  
>     // 1) outermost block scope of A::N::f, before the use of i  
>     // 2) scope of namespace N  
>     // 3) scope of namespace A  
>     // 4) global scope, before the definition of A::N::f  
> }
> ```

I believe 3.4.1/6 ignores the lookup of a name used in a *function-body* that is found in the function's *parameter-declaration-clause*, as shown below:

```
void f(int i) { std::cout << i << '\n'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>That paragraph is not relevant to your example, because in your example `i` is not "A name [...] that is a member of namespace `N`"</strike>

The start of the sentence should be parsed like this:

Let F be a function.
Let N be a namespace.
Let X be a name.

If X is used in the definition of F after F’s declarator-id and X is a member of namespace N ...

**Edit**: I've been persuaded by the comments that my interpretation above is wrong. I've created https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/451 to request that paragraph be rephrased.

However this is wrong too:

> I believe 3.4.1/6 ignores the lookup of a name used in a function-body that is found in the function's parameter-declaration-clause,

Firstly, obviously `i` *is* found by name lookup, otherwise function parameters would be unusable!

Secondly, 3.3.3 [basic.scope.block]/2 says that `i` has "block scope" beginning at its point of declaration and ending at the closing brace of the function definition. 3.4.6/6 says *"shall be declared before its use in the block in which it is used"* and that is true in this case. `i` is declared before it is used (its point of declaration is before it is used) and is declared in the block in which it is used (the outermost block scope of the function).

Comment: Are you sure "that is a member of namespace N" appertains to "A name" and not "a function"?

Comment: @T.C. yes, because of the intermediate clause "following the function’s declarator-id" which clearly applies to the name, not the function, and it would make no sense to talk about the name, then the function, then the name, then the function. The subject of the sentence is the name, not the function it is used in.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Could you please show me the paragraph that handles the case shown on my question?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm not sure...if `X` is a member of namespace `N`, then how does the final "if `N` is a nested namespace, shall be declared before its use in one of `N`’s enclosing namespaces" make any sense?

Comment: The scope of the parameter is defined by 3.3.3 [basic.scope.block]/2, so even if you read "that is a member of a namespace N" as referring to the function, `i` has "block scope" and is declared in the block before its use in the block.

Comment: @T.C. hmm, maybe you're right ... although in that case I'd say that "a function following the function’s declarator-id that is a member of namespace N" is in drastic need of rewording

Comment: @Belloc, in terms of the example from the standard, `i` is found in the "outermost block scope of `A::N::f`, before the use of `i`"

Comment: @JonathanWakely `That paragraph is not relevant to your example, because in your example i is not "A name [...] that is a member of namespace N"` neither is `i` a member of namespace N in the example in the Standard.

Comment: Well in the standard example `i` isn't declared at all! If it was declared somewhere then name lookup would not continue looking in enclosing scopes, which is what the example is trying to show.

Comment: [basic.scope.block]/1 says that "a name declared in a block [...] has *block scope*". Is that a statement of the form A => B or of the form A :<=> B? Is a function-parameter declared inside a compound-statement? Or are these just language-lawyer questions, since it's clear from its placement that /2 implies that a function parameter has block scope?

Comment: @JonathanWakely `i is declared before it is used (its point of declaration is before it is used) and is declared in the block in which it is used (the outermost block scope of the function).` i is declared in the *declarator*, not in the *function-body*. See the grammar for *function-definition* in 8.4.1/1.

Comment: I never said it's declared "in the function-body". The "outermost block scope" of a function includes declarations of the function parameters, see 3.3.3/2. And its scope is what determines whether it is in scope and so can be found by name lookup. ... I'm not sure what you're driving at, as you trying to suggest function parameters can't be used in a function, or just that there is a defect in the wording?

Comment: @JonathanWakely All I'm saying is that whoever wrote this paragraph forgot to include the lookup of a name which is found in the function's *parameter-declaration-clause*, which is **not** in the outermost block scope of the function. AFAIK, this outermost block scope coincides with the *compound statement* in the *function-body*. I can't see anything in 3.3.3/2 saying that the outermost block scope of a function includes the *parameter-declaration-clause*.

Comment: No, "block scope" does not coincide with the compound statement. Block scope is not a single region like the compound statement. For a function with two parameters, they both have block scope, but that scope starts at a different place for each parameter. The C standard agrees, in 6.2.1/4: _"If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block."_

Comment: In your original example `i` is declared in the **outermost block scope of `f`, before the use of `i`** which is the case (1) in the example in the standard. If the standard meant "in the compound statement of the function definition" it would say that, or would say "outermost block", but instead it refers to block scope, which 3.3.3/2 says includes the parameters.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I've just realized the *outermost block scope* of a function is not even defined in the C++ Standard (C++11 and C++14). Therefore when I wrote `I believe 3.4.1/6 ignores the lookup of a name used in a function-body that is found in the function's parameter-declaration-clause, ...` looks pretty legitimate to me, given this imprecision in the Standard, and could hardly be considered an error.

Comment: Block scope is defined, and "outermost" has its usual English meaning. If you insist there's a problem then [report an issue](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-library-issue)

Comment: @JonathanWakely The problem is that "outermost block scope" is in the example, not in normative text. The normative text says "shall be declared before its use in the block in which it is used or in one of its enclosing blocks" - note "block", not "block scope" - and according to [stmt.block], "block" means the compound statement.

Comment: @JonathanWakely `If you insist there is a problem then report an issue`. [Done](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/vBhd9vaeZ6g/88s750GtZ9oJ).